# WPF Textbox Flow direction issue with Arabic language

Tags: wpf, winforms, arabic

I am working on an application which supports many languages including Arabic. I am observing an odd behavior in the WPF text box while entering the values but strangely the same is working fine in a Windows Form text box.

All I am doing is this

1. Create a Text Box and keep it's flow direction to the default value which is LeftToRight
2. Change the language of the app to Arabic.
3. Type the following letter one by one in the text box 
      1
      a
      2
      j

   (where a and j denotes any two Arabic character).

Result :
Wpf Text box shows the value as 1j2a
While the Win forms text box displays it as j2a1.

Since Arabic is right to left , so the value shown by Win form is correct but that of WPF is wrong.

Wpf displays the correct value if we type the first character as Arabic and then enter any non-Arabic character.

Also, if I set the FlowDirection of the TextBox to RightToLeft, then WPF textbox works fine. But that will make my string move to the right and the app will have alignment issues.

Does anyone have any idea on why WPF text box shows the incorrect value while windows forms works fine ?

Also, can we keep the text aligned to left if we set the flow direction as RightToLeft ?

Comment: What if u make textbox flowdirection="RightToLeft"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also, if I set the FlowDirection of the TextBox to RightToLeft, then WPF textbox works fine. But that will make my string move to the right and the app will have alignment issues.

That kinda says you're having bigger problems than basic alignment. The whole point of `FlowDirection` is to allow those non native `LeftToRight` readers to have a native UX in your application.

string moving to the right is what it should be and that's what your Arabic users would expect.

[Microsoft Home Page in en-US](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx)

[Same page in ar-iq](http://www.microsoft.com/ar-iq/default.aspx)

There is a reason why not just characters look different, but the actual text-flow as well(It's what users of that language would expect)

If you're sure you want to keep the content aligned left even when `FlowDirection` is reversed, apply a `Style.Trigger` to do so accordingly but do look into how your UX feels.

```
<TextBox>
  <TextBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
              Value="Left" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="FlowDirection"
                  Value="RightToLeft">
          <!-- "Right" - HorizontalContentAlignment with FlowDirection="RightToLeft" is
               the same end render visually as "Left" - HorizontalContentAlignment with
               FlowDirection="LeftToRight" -->
          <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                  Value="Right" />
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

**Update:**

As the OP now states the control's actually a `TextBlock` the above `Style` would look like:

```
<TextBlock>
  <TextBlock.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
      <Setter Property="TextAlignment"
              Value="Left" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="FlowDirection"
                  Value="RightToLeft">
          <Setter Property="TextAlignment"
                  Value="Right" />
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thank but the problem with the above solution is that it won't work on a TextBlock as it doesn't have the HorizontalContentAlignment property. And we cannot use the Label as it doesn't provide TextWrapping feature.   
Is there any way we can align the text to left in a textblock while keeping the flowdirection as Right to Left ?

Comment: @SumitBakshi Well how am I to assume it's a `TextBlock` when your question title says "WPF **Textbox** ...". This entire page only has `TextBlock`'s mentioned in your comments and not in your question. You'd need to make your questions clearer. Now for a `TextBlock` the equivalent for `HorizontalContentAlignment` is just `TextAlignment` so just replace `HorizontalContentAlignment` with `TextAlignment`.

Comment: Sorry about that but I needed in for both the control. Seems like setting the TextAlignment=Right for a textblock fixes this issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: There is one issue when the text is quite big and TextWrapping is set to Wrap, then once the text moves to next line then the alignment is not proper.

For e.g.  lets say my textbox/textblock can handle max of 5 chars in a line and after that it wraps
So if I type  12ggg1234 then I expect the text to be 12ggg in the first line and 1234 in the next. But on setting the Flowdirection=RightToLeft and TextAlignment=Right, the text will be shown as 12gg in the first line and g1234 in the second line.

Please suggest on how to fix this alignment issue in case of text wrapping?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What if u make textbox flowdirection="RightToLeft"

in Xaml

```
<TextBox Name="TxtBox1" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
```

Comment: That will move the text to the right side which we don't want. Setting the horizontal content alignment is also not an option, since after entering we need to display the text in the TextBlock.